# Mac terminal lost git knowledge

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, git

When I opened terminal and went to a git repo, it would automatically show the branch I'm on with a big green check or red X if I had any changes.

Logged onto machine today and my bash profile was corrupted somehow. Now when I go to a git directory, things look like they always did for other folders, ie just the folder name.

I've only ever installed git apps from github.com or using `brew` so I'm not sure what feature I've lost from what.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not a standard shell feature. Were you using a custom prompt? What does your `.bash_profile` contain?

Comment: Nothing useful - it's pretty much from scratch after corruption. I know that git feature was not out of the box, but I have no idea where it came from to even fix it. Maybe when I ran install from github.com it just added that in, before I switched to brew? I'm gonna see about that now actually.

Comment: github for mac didn't do it